# How can I total a calculated column in a datatable using VB.NET, in such a way that the total updates whenever the underlying columns change?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I am developing a Request For Quote form in VB.NET. It has header information and a datagridview that holds the line items. The DGV is bound to a datatable dtRfqLines, where the column PriceTotal has been made to calculate from the columns PriceEach and Qty:

```
dtRfqLines.Columns("PriceTotal").Expression = "[Qty] * [PriceEach]"
```

I get the grand total from summing the PriceTotal column and puttting the result in a variable, which is bound to a textbox:

```
dblRfqTotal = dtRfqLines.Compute("SUM(PriceTotal)", "")
```

Now I want this grand total to update everytime one of the PriceEach or Qty values change, which in turn  changes PriceTotal. If I do that with a button it works but is very clunky - I want to tie the update to an event of the datatable or even the DGV. The problem is that whichever event I choose, the grand total seems to get calculated before the PriceTotal is calculated, so it is wrong. The events I have tried are CellValueChanged for the DGV and ColumnChanged for the DataTable.

If anybody has an idea how I can get the grand total to calculate after the PriceTotal is completely up to date, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried RowDataBound event?

Comment: There does not seem to be a RowDataBound event for the DataGridView conrol as there apparently was on the GridView control on VB6 - some people have found workarounds, but they don't seem to be seeking the same thing I am.

Comment: In CellValueChanged, have you tried in that even doing an If statement for price total? I.e. "if pricetotal is changed cell do multiplication, else, do nothing"

Comment: i would have done this with ComputedColumns directly on the SQL Server no code needed

Comment: @Nocturnal I considered doing that, but I wanted the total cost to update as soon as the user changes either quantity or price each and didn't know how that would work out. I haven't used a computed column in SS yet.

Comment: @MrBill its actually instant because it is computed on the Server itself. You don't need to add/alter events or anything

Comment: in the formula of the column on the SQL Server u can add something like this           (case when [PriceEach]=(0) OR [PriceEach] IS NULL then (0) else round([Qty]*[PriceEach],(2)) end) thats it whenever qty or priceEach is changed the effects are instant